# How many times can n be floor(sqrt(n)) - 1 while n > 0?

Tags: math

The full question is

Supposed we have a function

```
void foo(int n){
  int i = n;
  while(i > 0){
    //do an O(n) operation
    //do some O(1) operations
    i = sqrt(i) - 1;
  }
}
```

I just have to find the asymptotic bounds, but I can't do that until I figure out how many times the loop actually runs. Which I'm guessing is another summation involving a square root, but I'm not sure how to start.

Comment: This sounds like homework, so all you get is a hint: let m = log n.

Comment: this wasn't assigned, it was on a practice midterm on a question that was tagged as "harder than what you'll be tested on". But i'll tag it as homework anyways :3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to find you how many times the loop will execute.

If i < 2, then the loop will execute at most twice.

Therefore if i < 4 the loop will execute at most 3 times.

Therefore if i < 16 the loop will execute at most 4 times.

Therefore if i < 256 the loop will execute at most 5 times.

...

etc.

You see that if i < 2^(2^m), then the loop will execute at most (m+2) times.

This means that the order of the number of times it will execute is log(log(n)),

since i starts at n.

Thus the overall complexty is `O(n*log(log(n))`.

(That's if the number of O(1) operations in each iteration is constant.)

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. This is definitely an interesting run time. Also, how do the number O(1) operations change the overall complexity?

Comment: @Kyle if the "some" in "do some O(1) operations" depends on `n`, then the cost represented by that single line can no longer be disregarded. If, say, the "some" is actually `O(n^3)`, then that cost will push out to the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Same O(n log log n) as Petar but here are some sharper bounds. If i = floor(sqrt(i)) -1,

if n < 1, it loops zero time
if n < 2², it loops at most 1 time
if n < (2² +1)² = 5², it loops at most 2 times
if n < (5² +1)² = 26², it loops at most 3 times
if n < (26² +1)² = 677², it loops at most 4 times

According to the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A003095), this sequence (1, 2, 5, 26, 677, ...) is asymptotic to 1.22^(2^k) [and also the k-th number represents the number of binary trees of height at most k].  So for a number n, the number of loops is O(log log n) and your algorithm is O(n log log n).